# Unable to resolve @nrwl/angular

Tags: angular, angular-components, nx.dev

Getting below error when I'm trying to create a component in my angular application.

**Command**

```
ng generate  component  <component-name>
```

**Error**

```
Unable to resolve @nrwl/angular:component. Cannot find generator 'component' in D:\web-application\node_modules\@nrwl\angular\collection.json.
```

Has anyone encountered that.?

Below are the details of versions.

```
Angular CLI: 13.1.2
Node: 16.13.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solution to overcome from this error is add **old** schematics vesion in package.json and try to create the component.

- Current schematics version is *@schematics/angular 13.1.2*
- Update to below one

  ```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@schematics/angular": "11.2.19"
         - -
         - -
  ```

  }

Hope this will be helpfull to someone.

Thanks.